# What was the result of Sanji's battle in episode 794? (spoilers)

Tags: one-piece

In episode 794,

> Sanji fights his father. We don't see the ending/outcome of the battle, but we do see Sanji and his father after the battle.

Does this get shown later via flashbacks? Sanji had equal footing and/or the upper hand, but their interaction shows that Sanji did not win. What happened?

Answer (score 1):

Sanji lost the battle. I was almost sure but now I've confirmed it.

From the Brazilian [wiki](https://onepiece.fandom.com/pt/wiki/Vinsmoke_Sanji_Vs_Vinsmoke_Judge) last sentence (and translated by me):

> Judge stabs one of his soldiers and attacks Sanji with Denji Shaft, which makes an explosion sending the defeated Sanji far away.

Comment: I saw that, but Sanji acted like it wasn't much of anything.

Comment: In my honest opinion, it just shows that he really doesn't care about his father.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, generally that fight was till there, no more further, after that kick offing Sanji. Sanji didn't fought a fair fight actually! It doesn't compare many thing in that regards, but focusing on the on going Story, emotion that time.